# Using MIPS assembly in C

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I'm writing my own standard library implementation for MIPS. I'd like to be able to call a MIPS function from C. I have a simple function here:

```
PRINTLINE:
    jr $ra                 # just return for now
```

and I'd like to be able to call it thusly from C:

```
PRINTLINE();
```

How might I go about doing this? I need to know how to do this using GCC.

Answer (score 2):

To write functions in assembly that are callable from C, you need to follow the MIPS [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS).

The easiest way to do that would be to use GCC's [inline asm](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) extension to the C language, and allow GCC to take care of the details of the calling convention. Your example would be written something like this:

```
void PRINTLINE() {
  asm volatile("jr $ra");
}
```

You will need to study the GCC manual for the nuances of the `asm` statement.